# Pandas assign each row the mean of its bin

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (p1.head(7)):

```
     ColA
0    6.286333
1    3.317000
2    13.24889
3    26.20667
4    26.25556
5    60.59000
6    79.59000
7    1.361111
```

I can get the bin ranges using:

```
pandas.qcut(p1.ColA, 4)
```

Is there a way I can create a new column where each value corresponds to the mean value of the bin? I.e for each bin, (a,b], I want (a+b)/2

Comment: I think the mean value of the bin is ambiguous. Do you mean, for a given bin `[a,b)`, that you want `(a+b)/2` or the mean of every value that is in that bin? Or something else?

Comment: Exactly, I want (a+b)/2. Will update question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the `retbins` option on `qcut`.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.random(100)*100, columns=['val1'])

pctiles = pandas.qcut(df['val1'],4,retbins=True)
pctile_object = pctiles[0]
pctile_boundaries = pctiles[1]
```

Here `pctile_object` is just what qcut would return if you hadn't passed `retbins=True`, and `pctile_boundaries` is a numpy array of the interval boundaries.

```
import numpy
bin_halfway = pctile_boundaries[:-1] + (numpy.diff(pctile_boundaries)/2)
```

This gives us the halfway points of the bins.

Now we make a dataframe with just the interval names (as strings) and the halfway points.

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'quartile boundaries': pctile_object.levels, 
                        'midway point': bin_halfway})
```

Finally, merge the bin halfway points back into the original dataframe.

```
df['quartile boundaries'] = pctile_object
pandas.merge(df,df2,on='quartile boundaries')
```

Then you can drop `quartile boundaries` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to utilize @exp1orer 's logic:

```
def midway_quantiles(feature_series,q=4):
    import pandas as pd
    pctiles = pd.qcut(feature_series,q,retbins=True)
    pctile_object = pctiles[0]
    df1= pd.DataFrame({"feature":feature_series,"q_bound": pctile_object})
    pctile_boundaries = pctiles[1]
    import numpy as np
    bin_halfway = pctile_boundaries[:-1] + (np.diff(pctile_boundaries)/2)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"q_bound": pctile_object.cat.categories, 
                            "midpoint": bin_halfway})
    df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on="q_bound",how="left")
    return df3["midpoint"]
```